# Error when installing docker on Debian 9 stretch: repository ... does not have a Release file

Tags: debian, software-installation, docker

When trying to install docker on Debian 9.8 I get the following error message when running `sudo apt update` or `sudo apt-get update`:

> ```
> E: The repository 'cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 9.8.0 Stretch - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20190216-12:51] stretch Release' does not have a Release file. 
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
> ```

On Stack Overflow someone told me to:

> You can find the packages list in Debian in /etc/apt/sources.list (open it with root permissions to edit it). So go there, and find that CD source, and delete that line.

But I don't exactly know which lines to delete:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.8.0 _Stretch_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20190216-12:51]/ stretch contrib main
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.8.0 _Stretch_ - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20190216-12:51]/ stretch contrib main
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib
```

Answer (score 2):

You should comment ( or remove) the second line in your `sources.list`.

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.8.0 Stretch - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20190216-12:51]/ stretch contrib main
#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.8.0 Stretch - Official i386 DVD Binary-1 20190216-12:51]/ stretch contrib main
```

To edit your sources use:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Or through ( select your preferred test editor):

```
sudo apt edit-sources
```

Keep only the following lines:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
```

Save with <kbd>Ctrl + O</kbd> , <kbd>Enter</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl + X</kbd> then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

docker-ce isn't available for i386.

[OS requirements](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/)

> To install Docker CE, you need the 64-bit version of one of these Debian or Raspbian versions:
>
> Buster 10
>
> Stretch 9 (stable) / Raspbian Stretch
>
> Docker CE is supported on x86_64 (or amd64), armhf, and arm64 architectures.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, how do I save the file? The hint is: ^O save
but just typing it wont do. Yea, I'm a linux newbie

Comment: `^O` means ctrl-O, hold down the `ctrl` and press `O`

Comment: @JustMe did you need to install `docker-ce`?